# The top of the English character is not aligned with the top of his line In UITextKit

Tags: ios, swift

Configure the text of the system ：

```
func prepareTextSystem()  {

    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    layoutManager.delegate = self
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
}
```

Obtained paths:

```
   let glyphaRect = layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer!)

    let glyphPosition = layoutManager.location(forGlyphAt: index)
    let lineUsedRect = layoutManager.lineFragmentUsedRect(forGlyphAt: index, effectiveRange: nil)
    let pointY = lineUsedRect.origin.y + glyphPosition.y

    if index == 0 {
        firstCharPath = UIBezierPath(rect: glyphaRect)//the first char Rect

        lineUsedRectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: lineUsedRect)//the whole lineUsedRect
        baseLinePath = UIBezierPath()//Baseline
        baseLinePath?.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: pointY))
        baseLinePath?.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: Screen_W, y: pointY))
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

Draw:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if let path = firstCharPath {
        path.stroke()
    }
    if let path = lineUsedRectPath {
        path.stroke()
    }
    if let path = baseLinePath{
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

If the textStorage store string "Ye" ,represent like this :
[image]

If the textStorage store string "有y"(the first char is Chinese character) ,represent like this :
[image]

Question:

1. Why english character's top is not aligned with the line,But Chinese character's top is aligned well?

2.How can I get English character's top position?

Comment: I think maybe some kind of font will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aligned in both cases is correct. And the same.

The Chinese character used all the space nicely (above and below) and appears to be aligned to the top.

For English characters just a part of the space is used. Above it there is still extra space for special reading sign. It us aligned to the top.

Think about the underline _ symbol. That has plenty of white space above but hardly below.

The Æ is already high. The space reserved for the small dot on top of Å is causing your problems.

Comment: Is there any way to get this character's extra space height In UITextKit system?

Comment: Not without going in detail in the image itself. So basically not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not aligned with the top, because there are characters that are potentially taller. Point in case:

YŸ

Comment: Is there any way to get the  character **'Y'** 's top left position? I mean every glyph 's individual left top position.